# chrome.webrequest.onBeforeSendHeaders never called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function (req) {
  console.log("hello");
  debugger;
});
```

I have this in my background page of my extension, and the callback function is never called. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`webRequest` events [require filters to be set](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#subscription) to work properly. Also, make sure you have the required permissions - you need host permissions for the URLs you want to catch.

Example to catch all (you may want to be careful with that though):

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function (req) {
    console.log("hello");
    debugger;
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
);
```